# Change button color in swift

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ipad

How to change button color, while button is pressed. Like in calculator app. When finger is out button, it should return to default color. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For your button, change the color from your default color to a highlighted color for TouchDown control event and nevert the colors back to your default color on the TouchCancel and TouchDragExit control events.

```
    button.addTarget(self, action: "changeButtonColors:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "revertButtonColors:", forControlEvents: .TouchCancel)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "revertButtonColors:", forControlEvents: .TouchDragExit)

    func changeButtonColors(button: UIButton) {
        button.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    }

    func revertButtonColors(button: UIButton) {
        button.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: .Normal)
    }
```